# Error while executing spring boot

Tags: maven, jsp, spring-boot

I was trying to execute jsp using spring boot but Iam getting error instead of displaying body of jsp it is displaying the jsp file name itself.IDE I was using was STS.In STS I choose springstarterproject->web

My pom.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>assignment4</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>springboot-index9</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.13.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

This is my `Controller` class

```
 @Controller
    public class IController {
         @RequestMapping(value="/first")  
            public String bankname(){  
                return "success";  
            } 
    }
```

main program which starts the springboot application

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringbootIndex9Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringbootIndex9Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

This is my application.properties

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

And my `success.jsp` is

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
welcome
</body>
</html>
```

The path I used was http://localhost:8080/first
[image]
The project structure is as shown in the picture

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: When iam running the application Iam not able to display the body message of jsp

Comment: what are the contents of web.xml

Comment: <!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
</web-app>

Answer (score 0):

Seems i got your problem. Perhaps you will have to add a dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Add this dependency and try !